# Why am I getting ConnectionError (53000) signaling error with Twilio in browser?

Tags: twilio

I have a simple method for getting a new twilio voice client...

```
  export const createTwilioDevice = (_token) => new Twilio.Device(
    _token,
    {
      logLevel: 0,
      answerOnBridge: true,
      codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"],
    }
  );
  TwilioDevice.value = createTwilioDevice();
  TwilioDevice.value.on("registered", () => {
      console.info("Twilio.Device ready to make and receive calls!");
  });
  TwilioDevice.value.on("incoming", handleIncomingCall);
  TwilioDevice.value.on("tokenWillExpire", handleTokenWillExpire);
  TwilioDevice.value.on("error", handleCallError);
  await TwilioDevice.value.register();
```

It was working but now I am getting

> ConnectionError: ConnectionError (53000): Raised whenever a signaling connection error occurs that is not covered by a more specific error code.

What could have caused this to start happening?

Comment: Have your tried https://networktest.twilio.com/ to see if there are any underlying network issues?

Comment: Video insights said it failed but everything else passed

Comment: From what I gather, it is a underlying networking issue. Does it work when the client is using another network? The next step would be to a support ticket with Twilio on what you tried so far and some debug logs for them to look at.

Comment: It looks like I can see a little more debugging info in the request tabs under some 100 status code. I should be back to this in a week or so and I will update what I find but I would recommend others start in the network tab instead of console.

Comment: Hi @Jackie, were you able to resolve this issue? I'm having the same issue with the [voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-ruby](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-ruby). Even when using the dockerized version, network switching didn't help either. 
[Reported here on Github issue as well](https://github.com/twilio-labs/code-exchange/issues/49)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same err, in my case, a client forgot to settle a bill for twillio testing account)

Comment: This is the answer right here. Had exactly the same problem and would've never guessed. How it doesn't have a specific error code for such case is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone in the future, I just had this same ConnectionError 53000 and it was caused by having a blank space character in the identity string used to get the Twilio AuthToken.

As of today, the Twilio docs specifically state:

> The identity may only contain alpha-numeric and underscore characters. Other characters, including spaces, or exceeding the maximum number of characters (121), will result in not being able to place or receive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio currently serving this service to only specific region

1. United States (US1)
2. Ireland (IE1)
3. Australia (AU1)

Read Official Document: https://www.twilio.com/docs/global-infrastructure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I tried to set up a Twilio device using the https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-ruby.

The issue that caused this error in my case was that I was using Account SID from the Test Credentials instead of Live Credentials.

In the case of Test Credentials, no actual call is made, for making an actual voice call you have to use Live Credentials. [Docs Reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials#test-calls).

Check your US region Twilio Test/Live Credentials at this [link](https://console.twilio.com/us1/account/keys-credentials/api-keys)